# Create missing auto increment attribute with rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I'm writing a migration to convert a non-rails app into the right format for rails - one of the tables for some reason does not have auto increment set on the id column.  Is there a quick way to turn it on while in a migration, maybe with `change_column` or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute an SQL statement.

```
statement = "ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `id` `id` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(statement)
```

Note this is just an example. The final SQL statement syntax depends on the database.

Comment: thanks alot @Simone Carletti, wasted whole day to solve the problem, but now it's solved and thanks DGM too, for posting question specific to my case. Can you both give me idea on writing stored procedures in rails 4.1 in a fancy way, hoping you guys will help me again. Happy coding.

Comment: I don't know of much activity in rails using stored procedures - some corners of rails have little use for the more powerful sides of SQL, others just don't know about it...   anyway, at the very least you could use this same form to write the SQL to create the stored procedure.

Answer (score 6):

If you're on postgesql, a single request won't make it. You'll need to create a new sequence in the database.

```
create sequence users_id_seq;
```

Then add the id column to your table

```
alter table users
    add id INT UNIQUE;
```

Then set the default value for the id

```
alter table users
    alter column id
         set default nextval('users_id_seq');
```

Then populate the id column. This may be quite long if the table has many rows

```
update users
    set id = nextval('users_id_seq');
```

Hope this helps postgresql users...

Answer (score 5):

The [Postgres answer by @jlfenaux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713508/939860) misses out on the [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) type, which does all of it for you automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl add tbl_id serial;
```

[More details in this related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)