# how to apply autoincrementation in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, auto-increment

I was doing a shopping list project in ruby on rails. While creating the table named products, by mistake I have removed the autoincrement option from id field of my table products.

Can any one tell me ,how can I reinsert the option of `autoincrement` in table through migration.

my product table is as follows:-

```
  id serial NOT NULL,
  shopping_list_id integer NOT NULL,
  product_name character varying(255) DEFAULT 'null'::character varying,
  product_category character varying(255),
  quantity integer,
  status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'OPEN'::character varying,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

my product table is referencing my `shopping_list` table.

I am using `Postgresql` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can do by simply executing the SQL statements, but for `Postgresql users` you need to create a new sequence in the database.

This is mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182193/create-missing-auto-increment-attribute-with-rails-migration).